# Analyzing categorical data where the last category is unbounded

Tags: data-visualization, survival, censoring, calibration

This is a bit of a long-winded data vis question.

We're gathering data from a water quality test measuring fecal contamination.  The test measures fluorescence in 11 discrete chambers.  The water is known to be more contaminated as more of the chambers fluoresce and there's a non-linear way to quantify the water's contamination based on the chamber count.  That is, one chamber corresponds to a contamination level of 2, five chambers is 46, ten chambers is 210 and all eleven chambers is.. an unknown level greater than 210.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to present that last case.  I can plot contamination levels but how should I visualize or analyze "greater than 210?"  Is there a term for this?  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a case of right censoring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? If its just visualize it, why not just put in a bar graph and label it >210. The subset of statistics that delas with censored data is called survival analysis, so that is another term you will want to look into, but if you outline a bit more about what you are trying to do, I can give a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinal regression (e.g., proportional odds model) is an excellent way to analyze continuous or discrete ordinal Y.  Among other advantages, it allows for arbitrarily many ties at any Y value.  You can define all the categories as pertaining to a single measurement value except the last can refer to Y > 210.  You don't need to consider that last value as censored; it's just a category. [You'd need to consider it as censored if it corresponded to an inner category.]

From an ordinal model with such a setup you can estimate effects (odds ratio for prop. odds model) and quantiles (as long as the estimated quantile of Y < 210).  You can't estimate the mean without modeling what is going on with censoring.

My RMS course notes go into detail.  A link to the notes is at https://hbiostat.org/rms